# Reading data from a tab separated .txt and plotting it wrt index number and obtain ACF and PACF plots.. (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

To Obtain ACF and PACF plots.

I tried importing the data like this

```py
df_icecream = pd.read_csv(data_path, sep='\t')
df = df_icecream.T

#print first 5 rows of the dataframe

for i in range(5):
    index_df = I;
    print(i,df.iloc[i])
```

output:

```sh
0 Series([], Name: 0, dtype: float64) 
1 Series([], Name: -0.089755,dtype: float64) 
2 Series([], Name: -0.0017159, dtype: float64)
3 Series([], Name: 0.34754, dtype: float64)
4 Series([], Name:-0.16361, dtype: float64)
```

But i am unable to plot it

Answer (score 0):

[Statmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots.plot_acf.html) have functions that allow you to easily plot ACF and PACF just by passing the series.

It would be something like

```
import statmodels.api as sm

sm.graphics.tsa.plot_acf(df_icecream[some_col], lags=the_number_lags_you_want)
```

### EDIT

I'll be a bit more descpritive, first install statsmodels if you don't have already with `pip install statsmodels` after you do that you can do:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100), columns=["A"]) # Use your DataFrame instead
_ = sm.graphics.tsa.plot_acf(df["A"])
_ = sm.graphics.tsa.plot_pacf(df["A"])
```

These are the outputs:

[image: ACF]
[image: PACF]

Comment: 1. I am unable to import the module, so I tried 
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf, plot_pacf #tsa: time series analysis

2. This is the order of my data, I am unable to perform row operation 
0

-0.089755

-0.0017159

0.34754
-0.16361
...
2.3005
1.7691
0.32403
-0.24061
0.1

------
1811 rows × 0 columns

Comment: @sayantansen Did you installed statsmodels? I'm not sure what you meant by row operation